# How can I convert a TypedObject to a nested dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, pyamf

I am using pyAMF and I do receive a [`TypedObject`](http://api.pyamf.org/0.6.1/pyamf.TypedObject-class.html) that is in fact a nested dictionary. I want  to convert this to a python dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to wrap it in `dict(obj)` or call `obj.copy()` to convert it:

```
>>> type(o)
<class 'pyamf.TypedObject'>
>>> type(o.copy())
<type 'dict'>
>>> o.copy()
{'abc': 123}
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but what I tested initially `dict(obj)` doesn't work. Still, your second variant works!

Comment: @Sorin, glad it helped! Strange, since dict(obj) works for me, which makes sense since TypedObject inherits directly from dict.

Comment: Probably it has something to do with the fact that I do have a nested dictionary.

Comment: Hmm, the dict(obj) worked for me, even for nested TypedObjects and dicts.